# Core Audio: How to store buffers in RAM before writing to disk or deleting?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-audio

My app uses Core Audio to analyse audio buffers, recording over long time periods but only presenting a few samples of that audio to the user. To date, I have been writing everything to disk before selectively deleting files. However, it seems that the write operation is quite demanding of the hardware, and can occasionally trigger crashes if used too much.

I'd love to have a way to avoid the write operation unless necessary, which could be done by storing audio buffers (say 1 minutes worth) in RAM before either writing to disk or releasing them from memory if not needed.

Can anyone please advise of the most efficient way that this can be done?

```
renderErr = AudioUnitRender(rioUnit, ioActionFlags,
                                    inTimeStamp, bus1, inNumberFrames, THIS->bufferList);

Analysis of buffer....

OSStatus s;

s = ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(THIS->mAudioFileRef, inNumberFrames, THIS->bufferList);
```

What would be the best container for storing the buffer before selectively running a loop to write the buffer to disk...? What would  be the best way to release the memory?

Comment: Writing to disk shouldn't be demanding of the hardware, much less causing crashes. ExtAudioFileWriteAsyc() is very efficient. Your code is causing the crash. Can you share more of your code? e.g. are you calling ExtAudioFileDispose() to flush any pending writes to disk?

Comment: The crashes were occurring after several hours of constant writing, and mostly on older hardware with more limited resources. I tested a few avenues (and had some help from Apple support). It was triggering 'kernal panics', which are very unusual and wasn't linked to specific code, rather to the hardware not coping after a while. Yes, I use ExtAudioFileDispose. I managed to massively reduce the incidence of crashes by reducing the amount of time spent writing (taking pauses), and when run with no writing there were no crashes, and so concluded it was the writing that was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lock-free circular queue or fifo using an array of samples of size 2646000+1 or larger could store 1 minute of mono audio at 44.1 ksps in RAM.  Most iOS devices won't have a problem allocating 6MB or more of memory for a queue or fifo.  Displaying, analyzing or writing this data to disk can be done in another thread via a periodic polling or displaylink timer (emptying from the tail of the circular queue or fifo).  The memory used for this array can be released after the audio unit is stopped.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it was much easier than I thought.